# Cordova does not vibrate as expected on iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, iphone-vibrate

In my Ionic 3.20 + cordova ios 4.5.4 app with cordova-plugin-vibration 3.0.1 and compiled against XCode 9.4.1, `@ionic-native/vibration`  behaves this way on iPhone 7:

- vibrates with a default duration if a single duration value is given;
  e.g. `vibrate(40);` will vibrate ~500ms
- doesn't vibrate at all if a sequence is given; e.g. `vibrate([100, 100,
  100]);`

The same app compiled on Android works well and vibrates as expected.

Comment: Which iOS version you're testing on?

Comment: On iOS the specified time is ignored, it vibrates for a pre-set amount of time. Documentation: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-vibration/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue with iOS. From the plugin's [README](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-vibration#ios-quirks):

> **OS Quirks**
> time: Ignores the specified time and vibrates for a pre-set amount of time.
>
> ```
> navigator.vibrate(3000); // 3000 is ignored
> ```

Comment: I am now trying to find a workaround, at least to differentiate short/long vibrations. Some people are using other Sound IDs that trigger vibrator https://github.com/tatatananana/cordova-plugin-vibration/commit/25c804bbe42b7eda0c8a6adf87c1f733d92f069c but it seems like the official Apple documentation does not even has a list of available sounds. Unofficial lists exist but I can't find the exact meaning of 1352 nor if other integers exist http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/AudioServices